# perl foreach return-value blank

Tags: perl

This sub dies:

```
sub _log {
  foreach(@_) { 
    print $_ . "\n";  
  }
  #return 1; # This fixes it but I want to understand the why
}
_log("log something") || die "I died";
```

The print in this sub is returning 1 but the sub itself is returning ''. I thought that foreachs return the return of the last statement inside it. That must not be the case.

Why isn't this sub returning 1?

Comment: Why you're checking on return value of _log() when you're not returning success value?

Comment: for some context I have a sub calling a sub that calls _log. For other reasons the first sub calls the second with a '|| die". The _log is making that '|| die' hit.

Comment: Just remove `|| die` as _log is not returning anything to check against.

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend using the `or` operator over `||`, since the latter has higher precedence, which is often not what you want and may cause hard to detect bugs, such as this one: `open my $fh, "<", "nonexistentfile.txt" || die $!` (will never die, despite the file not existing)

Comment: The sub that calls _log calls other things that CAN fail. When they don't, the 'fail' from _log is still past to the first sub.

Comment: @TLP Thanks! I'll be sure to do that.

Comment: @TLP Can you please link to some documentation on the differences between or and ||. Thanks!

Comment: @Bill [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) has information on all operators and their precedence. They do the same thing, they just have different precedence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value which `foreach` evaluates to is effectively undefined behavior – the documentation [does not mention](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) any return value. Always use an explicit `return` to avoid such mistakes, and do not rely on the value of statement-level constructs like `while`, `for`, or `if`.

In practice, such constructs do have a consistent return value – the value of the last thing evaluated. For example, `foo() if bar()` is compiled the same way as `bar() and foo()`, which  does have a well-defined return value.

Comment: you can rely on them to the extent you know what they do; it isn't that complicated.  (but yes, an explicit return is better.)

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` never produces a result, so a sub ending with a foreach will return just like a sub ending with `return;`, that is, `undef` in scalar context (as in this example) and an empty list in list context.